# Parse xml based on sibling parent/sibling value

Tags: python, lxml

Given the following xml:

```
<Title>
<EST>
  <EST_Start_Date>2009-09-21</EST_Start_Date>
  <EST_End_Date>2015-12-31</EST_End_Date>
  <EST_Version>
    <Vendor_ID>asdf-200130</Vendor_ID>
    <Master_Type_HD_SD>SD</Master_Type_HD_SD>
  </EST_Version>
  <EST_Version>
    <Digital_SKU>205119</Digital_SKU>
    <Vendor_ID>qwer-205119</Vendor_ID>
    <Master_Type_HD_SD>HD</Master_Type_HD_SD>
  </EST_Version>
</EST>
</Title>
```

And a `Title` node:

```
titles = node.xpath("//Title")
for title in titles:
    est=title.find('EST')
    hd_vendor_id = ?
```

How would I pull the HD vendor ID, in this case `qwer-205118`? The lxml call should be relative to the given Title node, because there are mutliple titles in the xml document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the power of XPath! By using a predicate on the EST_Version element, you can find the one with HD-Master_Type:

```
titles = node.xpath("//Title")
for title in titles:
    hd_vendor_id = title.xpath(
        "./EST/EST_Version[Master_Type_HD_SD='HD']/Vendor_ID)")
```

If you only need the vendor IDs, you can use one single XPath:

```
node.xpath("//Title/EST/EST_Version[Master_Type_HD_SD='HD']/Vendor_ID/text()")
```

---

If you need more from each EST element, you can either stick with your syntax:

```
titles = node.xpath("//Title")
for title in titles:
    est=title.find('EST')
    hd_vendor_id = est.xpath("./EST_Version[Master_Type_HD_SD='HD']/Vendor_ID)"
```

or, for example, use XPath to select the EST elements right away:

```
ests = node.xpath("//Title/EST")
for est in ests:
    hd_vendor_id = est.xpath("./EST_Version[Master_Type_HD_SD='HD']/Vendor_ID)"
```